# How to to change the color of selected radio button's center circle

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to  change the color of selected radio button's center circle, I don't know how to apply css to acheive this. If I am not clear with my doubt please post a comment.

```
<div Name="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"></input>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"></input>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SCSS approach

The right way to do this is by looking at the variable `$custom-radio-indicator-icon-checked` in the **Compass setup** => `\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss`.

```
$custom-radio-indicator-icon-checked: str-replace(url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3E%3Ccircle r='3' fill='#{$custom-control-indicator-checked-color}'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), "#", "%23") !default;
```

Here you can find the use of `$custom-control-indicator-checked-color` which points you to the option(s) of changing color and background-color.

```
$custom-control-indicator-checked-color: $component-active-color !default;
$custom-control-indicator-checked-bg: $component-active-bg !default;
```

Hence, changing `$component-active-color` or `$component-active-bg`.

```
$component-active-color: $white !default;
$component-active-bg: theme-color("primary") !default;
```

So you can change the color directly inside the variable or on component level to change all indicators of the following components:

- custom checkbox
- custom radio
- dropdown
- nav-pills
- pagination
- list-group

---

### CSS approach

Now let's assume you don't have a SCSS setup and you're simply trying to **override the color by CSS**. You'll have to find the associated label's pseudo class `:after`.

```
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23fff'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

Here you're looking for the `fill` property. The hash sign (#) was replaced by `%23`. Other than that it's a hexadecimal value. That's for the circle!

Changing the `border-color` and `background-color` for the checkbox itself is defined on the pseudo class `:before`:

```
.custom-control-input.is-valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before, 
.was-validated .custom-control-input:valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: #34ce57;
    background-color: #34ce57;
}
```

Please note there's some additional weight (validation, state checked or not) to these selectors to make it work.